# TFS: ChangeType is Add,Edit either for Edit or for Add

Tags: tfs, changetype

1.txt is added and 2.txt is modified.

The problem is, the changeType is always "Add, Edit, Encoding"!

```
var tfs = ...;
var changeset = tfs.GetChangeset(new Uri("tfs path"), 999);
foreach (var w in changeset.Changes)
   Debug.Print( w.Item.ServerItem + " -> " + w.ChangeType );

//Output:
$/.../1.txt -> Add, Edit, Encoding
$/.../2.txt -> Add, Edit, Encoding
```

Does anybody know what happened to each file and why i always have these three types?

Thanks!

Comment: LOCs for an addition are all the lines of the file, LOCs for an edit are the difference between this version and the previous.

Answer (score 1):

A little late but happened to saw it unanswered so this is what i did:

```
var vcs = projects.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
foreach ( var w in changeset.Changes ) {
    w.Item.DownloadFile( tmpFile );
    var str = System.IO.File.ReadAllText( tmpFile );
    var bocs = GetCodeBytes( str, fileType.RemovesRegExp );
    try{
        Item previousItem = vcs.GetItem( w.Item.ItemId, Convert.ToInt32( iRevision - 1 ), true );
        previousItem.DownloadFile( tmpFile );
        var str2 = System.IO.File.ReadAllText( tmpFile );
        bocs = bocs - GetCodeBytes( str2, fileType.RemovesRegExp );
        changeTypeString = "mod";
    }
    catch{
        bocs = w.Item.ContentLength;
    }
}
```

*That's not a working code, it's just the basic idea*